# Javascript ES6 Destructuring - Identifier 'location' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a simple array of objects and want to get the location attribute of the first element:

```js
const companies = [
  { name: 'Google', location: 'Mountain View' },
  { name: 'Facebook', location: 'Menlo Park' },
  { name: 'Uber', location: 'San Francisco' }
];

const [{ location }] = companies; 
// expected: Mountain View but got Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 
//'location' has already been declared at <anonymous>:1:1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot redefine the global variable `location` as a constant. Had you used `let [{location}] = companies`, you wouldn't have got an error, but you would have had the wrong behavior as it would try to assign a value to `window.location` and redirect the page.

Possible solutions:

- Change the variable name (along with the property name)
- Wrap your code in a block (IIFE is not necessary in this case since we are using ES6)
- You can keep the property name and change the variable name, see the last example

```js
const companies = [
  {name: 'Google',loc: 'Mountain View'},
  {name: 'Facebook', loc: 'Menlo Park'},
  {name: 'Uber', loc: 'San Francisco'}
];

const [{loc}] = companies;
console.log(loc);

// Block scope
{
  const companies = [
    {name: 'Google', location: 'Mountain View'},
    {name: 'Facebook', location: 'Menlo Park'},
    {name: 'Uber', location: 'San Francisco'}
  ];
  const [{location}] = companies;
  console.log(location);
}

// Variable name doesn't have to be the same as property
const [{ location: loca }] = [{location: 'Mountain View'}]
console.log(loca);
```

Comment: I'd clarify the sentence "you cannot redefine the global variable X", in general only applies to constants on the same scope. You can write more `var` identical declarations, though

Comment: I don't get what you mean. What's wrong in what I said, and what code gives you that error? The OP is having a problem with the 'location' variable not the 'companies' variable

Comment: I don't get the same error. maybe you pasted it already in the console without reloading. What's happening with me using the same code is a page reload, because it's assigning to window.location

Comment: I stand corrected, it does allow it when I refresh the page and run it again

Comment: This would be the correct answer if only this weren't a ES6 question. Why IIFE? This is ES6. There are blocks.

Comment: @estus Agreed, I should have used blocks, fixed

Comment: `const [{ location: loc }] = companies` would work too and give you a local `const loc` in any scope

Comment: @CodingIntrigue Thanks, added to answer

Comment: A suggestiong to use `var` instead of `const` Why `var` and not `let`?

Comment: @Sukima Updated answer

Comment: @When you define a new variable on a different scope, that's shadowing the previous variable and the current scope can't see it; it is not redefining the variable. Since you are trying to be precise ;)

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that you're not wrapping your code inside a function.

If you use an IIFE (Immediately Invocated Function Expression) the same code will work.

The reason your code fails is because you can't declare a constant in the same scope, if the constant/variable name is already taken.

You could have used `var` instead of `const` but that would have assigned to `window.location`, effectively reloading the page and taking you to a 404 Page because that url doesn't exist.

That's why you should always write your code in an IIFE, to prevent global namespace pollution and nasty bugs that are hard to fix.

Here's the same code with an IIFE (added strict mode):

```js
(() => { // ES2015 IIFE
    "use strict";
    
    const companies = [
      { name: 'Google', location: 'Mountain View' },
      { name: 'Facebook', location: 'Menlo Park' },
      { name: 'Uber', location: 'San Francisco' }
    ];
    
    const [{ location }] = companies;
    console.log(location);
})();
```

Or better yet:

```js
{ // ES2015 block
    "use strict";
    
    const companies = [
      { name: 'Google', location: 'Mountain View' },
      { name: 'Facebook', location: 'Menlo Park' },
      { name: 'Uber', location: 'San Francisco' }
    ];
    
    const [{ location }] = companies; 
    console.log(location);
};
```

The use of the ES2015 block won't pollute the global scope, given that you'll be using only `let` and `const` (and not using `var`)

Also, always remember that not all the browsers are supporting ES2015 syntax yet, so for now the code must be transpiled using Babel JS or similar tools.

Comment: Answered after discussing the code with Juan Mendes in his answer

Comment: OP said: `want to get the location attribute of the first element:` Also note the comment from estus, a block should be used since it's ES6

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `location` has already been declared on global scope, as `window.location`.

To avoid this, this piece of code should not be executed in local scope, i.e. a block. This is ES6, while IIFEs are left-overs of ES5:

```
{
  ...
  const [{ location }] = companies; 
}
```

The typical use for ES6 is modular environment. Considering that current scope is CommonJS or ES6 module, the problem will never appear.

Comment: Please, also note that `var` inside ES2015 block scopes would pollute the global scope anyway, so you'd have to use only `const` and `let`

Comment: @Zorgatone That's correct. Generally, it is a good practice to not use `var` at all because it creates more problems than it solves. There's `no-var` rule in ESLint for this reason.

Comment: I commented just to make a note about that. Indeed it's good practice to use only `const` and `let` in ES6. But just to warn being careful when working in a group, or copy-pasting code without checking from other sources that it doesn't contain any `var` and replace with `let` if the same variable is not declared more than one time

Answer (score -3):

```
const companies = [
  { name: 'Google', location: 'Mountain View' },
  { name: 'Facebook', location: 'Menlo Park' },
  { name: 'Uber', location: 'San Francisco' }
];

console.log(companies[0].location);
```